# Cache:true ignored by resource

Tags: angularjs

I've added cache:true to my resource. But when I execute the resource method(no page refresh) once more, I see the request get sent to the server. How come that the resource isn't cached? Should I implement a $cacheFactory for this to work?

Resource:

```
 "use strict";
angular.module('afx.service')
    .factory('afx.service.resource.Terminal', ["$resource", function ($resource) {
        return $resource("/rest/terminals", {}, {
            /**
             * @method findTerminals
             * Find all terminals
             * @return {Array} Terminals
             */
            findTerminals: { method: "GET", isArray: true, cache: true}

        });
    }]);
```

Use of resource:

```
terminalsResource.findTerminals({}, function (data) {
                    $scope.loading = false;
                    $scope.terminals = data;
                }, function (response) {
                    var lStatus = response.status;
                    if (lStatus !== 401) {
                        growlerService.error("Could not refresh the terminals");
                    }
                });
```

Comment: may you show us the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works only in angular-resource.js v1.2.7 (not 1.0.7)

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement $cacheFactory to do it !

Look at here : [AngularJs: How to cache $http properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963766/angularjs-how-to-cache-http-properly/18963858#18963858)

Comment: implementing this, still makes a resource(GET, same URL) do 2 calls to the server

Comment: Are you doing F5 on browser ? beacause on F5 you'll always get 200 like status code

Comment: jep, I only updated angular.js to 1.2.7... Angular-Resource.js was stil 1.0.7. It works like a charm now, without implementing $cacheFactory.